# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' after deployment of application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I deployed the same application to 2 servers (test and producation) on IIS.

On the first server it works perfectly, but on the other one it doesn't.

I can connect, get data and also add anything... but I can't delete or update.

I keep getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '***' from origin '***' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource.

My startup configuration:

```
//ConfigureServices
   services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

 //Configure

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/API-{Date}.txt");
        app.UseStaticFiles();



        // app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this in the ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddCors ();
}
```

then in the Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
{
 app.UseCors (x => x.SetIsOriginAllowed (options => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod ().AllowAnyHeader ().AllowCredentials ());
 }
```

hope this help

Comment: thanks but i add them in the configure or configureservices?

Comment: the first one in ConfigureServices  and the second one in Configure after app.routing();

Comment: well Thanks, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this.

In your Startup.cs file

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
       services.AddCors(cfg =>
       {
            cfg.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
            {
                 policy.WithOrigins("list of origins to allow here")
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowCredentials()
                 .SetIsOriginAllowed((_) => true)
                 .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
            });
       });
  }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
     app.UseCors();
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{tag?}");
       });
  }
```

Do make sure Cors is called before the call to MVC.

**Secondly: Do this**

Check Authentication method being used on IIS, make sure its not set to Basic Authentication. I will say you turn off IIS Authentication.

**To Turn OFF IIS Authentication**

For Server-wide
Open IIS Manager > Click SERVERNAME on the left Pane > Select Authentication Under IIS Section > Select Authentication Type to Disable

For Site-wide
Open IIS Manager > Click Sites > Select Your Site > Select Authentication Under IIS Section > Select Authentication Type to Disable

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: well can you help me on how turning off the IIS authentication?